# Enabled/Disable controls in Xmlhttp Response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that has 3 to 4 divs with gridviews in each that get data loaded using Ajax Xmlhttp calls.

Now the problem is that I have checkboxes in the grid and need them to be disabled/enabled
when they load to the main page in the div.

When i set the Enabled=false tag in the ASPX page to the checkbox, the UI throws an "Object required" error.

Any advices on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `enabled=false` via javascript to html object?

Thenit should be `disabled="disabled"`

Can you try this?

Comment: Yes i have tried. I set Enabled=false in the aspx page. Im using an <asp:CheckBox>in the grid : <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPriority" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Eval("IsPriority")%>'  runat="server" />